# Sleuth TraceId missing in Netty HttpClient WRITE event if same 'reactor-http-nio' thread is used

Tags: spring-webclient, spring-cloud-sleuth, reactor-netty

Lately after `Spring Boot 2.7.6` (corresponding netty release), Sleuth TraceId is missing in the `WRITE` event of our custom `LoggingHandler` if same reactor-http-nio thread is used. First request using the new thread logs the traceId perfectly, subsequent request is missing the TraceId only for the `WRITE` event. `READ` event is fine.

We are currently on `Spring Boot 2.7.11` with latest Project Reactor and Sleuth dependencies.

```
HttpClient.create()
    .doOnRequest((request, connection) -> connection.addHandlerFirst(loggingHandler))


@Component
public class PayloadLogger extends LoggingHandler {

@Autowired
public PayloadLogger() {

    super(HttpClient.class, DEBUG, SIMPLE);
}

@Override
protected String format(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String event, Object arg) {

    if (arg instanceof ByteBufHolder byteBufHolder && StringUtils.equalsAny(event, WEBCLIENT_LOGGING_READ_EVENT, WEBCLIENT_LOGGING_WRITE_EVENT)) {

        var logMsg = byteBufHolder.content().toString(UTF_8);

        // WRITE
        if (WEBCLIENT_LOGGING_WRITE_EVENT.equals(event))
            return "Request Payload: " + logMsg;

        // READ
        if (WEBCLIENT_LOGGING_READ_EVENT.equals(event)) {
```